# No release history was found for the requested project

Tags: 7, drush

When I try to download [registry_autoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_autoload) via `drush dl registry_autoload` I get this error:

> No release history was found for the requested project

Is this an issue with the module's .info file, or something I'm doing wrong? How can I get this module using Drush, and if that is impossible can I just download and install the latest release? I don't want to install it if there's an error with the code.

Answer (score 1):

According to release [updates.drupal.org](https://updates.drupal.org/), the module has release candidates for Drupal 7.x as per:

- https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/registry_autoload/7.x

So try the following suggestions:

- Make sure your IP is not blocked by going to https://updates.drupal.org/
- Make sure your Drush recognise your Drupal root as 7.x (check `drush status`) and whether Drush can access the above endpoint by:

  ```
  drush ev 'echo file_get_contents("https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/registry_autoload/7.x");
  ```

  There could be a case that you are behind the firewall or corporate proxy, therefore the certificate could be not valid, so you'll have to configure your PHP's `curl` library either by importing the right certificate and mark it as trusted, ignoring it (not recommended) or use the non-secured connection to check for the new releases.